# How long does it take for rain drops cover a square?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider a square divided into $n \times n$ grid. Each rain drop falls from the sky and covers an $r \times r$ grid chosen uniformly at random within the square. What is the expected number of rain drops needed to cover the whole square?

To avoid boundary conditions, we can assume that the square is actually a [torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus). In other words, the top and the bottom of the square are glued together, while the left side and the right side of the squares are guled together.

If $r=1$, then this is the classical [coupon collector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem). It also gives an upper bound of $n^2 \log(n^2)$ for this rain drop model. I wonder if this model has already been studied? It seems to be natural extension of coupon collector.

Comment: How you define a "square torus"? You need to add how it is squared the torus. Probably you mean a structure with right angles, right? Like a simple picture frame.

Comment: For r=2 if they either fall on the previous ones or the uncovered area, it is still O(n^2 log n)

Comment: I think it will have the same asymptotic, because the number of squares that you gain should still be a random variable whose expectation is proportional to the fraction of uncovered squares, which is the main idea of the coupon collector derivation.

Comment: The result must depend on $r$ and $n$, and not just on the ratio $n/r$.  There must be an accounting of the degree of possible overlap if it is assumed that drops fall on an integer lattice, where $n, r \in \mathbb Z^+$ (as implied by the statement about $r = 1$ corresponding to the coupon collector problem).

Comment: @heropup To clarify my previous comment, it is clear that the number of squares gained in a drop is not a random variable whose distribution depends *only* on the fraction of uncovered squares. It also depends on the geometric distribution of these squares. But I conjecture that at least if $r$ is held fixed as $n \to \infty$ that this geometric contribution to the expectation can be absorbed into a constant factor. The question of $n \to \infty$ at fixed $r/n$ is also interesting as you mentioned in your answer (these are somehow the only interesting scales).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran $N = 10^5$ simulations for the case $r = 2$, $n = 8$, and the result fit extremely well to an inverse gamma distribution with parameters $(a, b) = (14.6313, 987.144)$, where I have used the parametrization $$f_X(x) =  \frac{e^{-b/x} \left(b/x\right)^a}{x \Gamma (a)}, \quad x > 0.$$  This would give a mean and variance of $\mu = 72.4176$, $\sigma^2 = 415.185$.

Of course, we should not expect this to be the same as $r = 1$, $n = 4$, which is the classic coupon collector's problem.

A simulation with $r = 3$, $n = 8$ gives another good inverse gamma fit, with $(a,b) = (12.1359, 329.206)$.

Perhaps someone else can find some relationship between $r, n$ and $a, b$, but I believe that the distribution of the number of drops needed is well-modeled as inverse gamma, even though I have no theoretical basis for it.

I am curious what would happen in the continuous case, with $\rho = r/n = 1/4$ but $n \to \infty$.  My intuition says that in the asymptotic case, the expectation and variance increase.